# Is there a way to regenerate Azure Blob Storage SAS token

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I use azure-sdk-for-js (NodeJS).
Particularly - @azure/storage-blob@12.6.0.

I have a service which generates SAS tokens and they expire in few minutes. I want somehow request new tokens after previous expire. And this should be done even in the middle of operation. Because when I upload big file to blob, in the middle SAS token expires and upload fails.

I have a worked example of what I need, but with EventHub.
I create event hub client with:

```
new EventHubProducerClient(eventHubHost, eventHubName, sasGenerator)
```

And `sasGenerator` is emplementation of `TokenCredential`. It returns generated `AccessToken` (which have SAS token and expiresOnTimestamp). And if I got it correctly, `EventHubProducerClient` use my `sasGenerator` to refresh tokens when needed.

I found that `BlobServiceClient` have similar argument `credential` which can have type of `TokenCredential`. But the same approach as with EventHub doesn't work:

```
new BlobServiceClient(blobHost, sasGenerator)
```

Example of Error:

```
RestError: Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header
```

I also was able to use generated SAS token with `AnonymousCredential` and it works. But I'm not able to upload big file to blob because the token expires earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below points ,if they can be worked around

1. The error `Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header` possibly may be due to an issue with your account name/key stored in the the config file or connection string.
   It may be due to permissions not in correct order .See [Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/issues/648)   And [valid permission order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas#specifying-permissions).
2. Came across this **[Article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-js/wiki/Customize-HTTP-Pipeline-and-Policies-to-Dynamic-Inject-SAS-During-Uploading)** on how to inject new SAS for an ongoing uploading .
   The scenario provides sample  to  request a new SAS token during the uploading instead of starting a new upload.

SEE:

1. [work-with-shared-access-signatures](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/storage/storage-nodejs-how-to-use-blob-storage.md#work-with-shared-access-signatures)
2. [Best practices using sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview#best-practices-when-using-sas)

Comment: Please stop posting article links, without actual content in your answers. Post any relevant code, explanations, etc. in your answer and only include links as additional resources.

Comment: The method described in the article **Customize HTTP Pipeline and Policies to Dynamic Inject SAS During Uploading**
should work, although it was written for the older version of azure blob storage library so you will need to port it currently. I have logged an issue for docs and samples improvement at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/17836